# Delete the line leading with non-numeric data and insert the text before a specific text format in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with thousands of lines of the format

```
unwantedtext1 
unwantedtext1
  50779       1   52476   52475   52481   52485
  50780       1   52485   52481   52480   52484
  .....
  .....
  unwantedText2
  50614  1.8837812e+001  7.0057003e+000  1.6900000e+002
  52200  4.6960466e+001 -2.5497744e+000  1.4950614e+002
  .....
  .....
unwantedtext3
unwantedtext3
```

In order to acheive my goal I have tried

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{3\}/p'   input.txt and also   # to remove the line with non numeric in beginning
grep '^[0-9][0-9][0-9]' input.txt  > output.txt
```

In the next step I have to add the text wantedText1 in the beginning of file and wantedText2 when the field 2 becomes a real number and not an integer anymore. so that output would be

```
wantedtext1 
wantedtext1
  50779       1   52476   52475   52481   52485
  50780       1   52485   52481   52480   52484
  .....
  .....
  wantedText2
  50614  1.8837812e+001  7.0057003e+000  1.6900000e+002
  52200  4.6960466e+001 -2.5497744e+000  1.4950614e+002
  .....
  .....
wantedtext3
wantedtext3
```

These wanted text  could be either echoed directly or could be input from other other. The data is space delimited and not tabs delimited.

Any suggestions using sed or awk?

Comment: What's wrong with replacing unwanted to wanted?

Comment: Hi Hamad,
yes, you can do that with awk, but it's bound to get really complicated and error-prone. Also, it's not going to be much faster than just parsing everything using a general-purpose scripting language like, let's say, python. Can you explain why you can't do that?

Comment: I have tried but I was not successful with the commands given above, so think there may be some problem with the syntax of parsing etc.. can you suggest me some way?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have to insert the wanted text to suit my format require and unwanted text to get deleted so that my file looks as required by the software.

Answer (score 1):

posix version (`--posix`on GNU sed)

```
sed '#n
1 {x;s/.*/WantedText2/;x
   a\
WantedText1
   }
/^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]\{3,\}/ {
   /^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]\{3,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[-0-9]\{1,\}\./ !p
   /^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]\{3,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[-0-9]\{1,\}\./ H
   }
$ {x;p
   a\
Wanted\
Text\
3
   }' YourFile
```

Selection and print in 1 sed

- set print only on `p` action
- pre load WantedText2 in holding buffer
- print WantedText1
- on line starting with number

  - if integer (not floating) as second number, print it
  - if floating as second number, append to hodling buffer
- if end is reached, load holding buffer and print it and add the wanted text 3
- cycle

Comment: can I have this wanted text in multiple lines? is it not possible to pipe it from a certain text file?  can you let me know how? thanks

Comment: how can I add wanted text 3 too, it is missing in your code too

Comment: multiple line for the selection  of delimiter ? should change the algorthm becasue sed work line by lione and in this case, need to load the file in buffer first or use sub selection with unwanted behaviour risk. For wanted text3, i adapt the reply code